# Horizontal scrolling from iframe to iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, horizontal-scrolling

I apologize if the title doesn't accurately describe what I'm looking for. I'm still pretty new to this stuff, and I'm not sure exactly of the terminology of what I'm trying to accomplish, but here is a picture of it:

[image]

In this image, I have displayed another HTML file using an iframe ("Max to Meet the Maniacs"). As you can also see, there is another header element containing another iframe below. I want the second iframe to position to the right of the first so that I can scroll horizontally between the two. I hope this makes sense. I'm deploying a static website, so I know that has limitations (not entirely sure what they are though). Any ideas?

Edit: Here's my HTML. I can post CSS if needed.

```
<section id="first" class="main center profile">

<header style="height:100%;width:100%">
    <iframe style="height:100%;width:100%" src="profile.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</header>

<header style="height:100%;width:100%">
    <iframe style="height:100%;width:100%" src="danny.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</header>

</section>
```

Comment: We need to see code, not images.

Comment: The images were necessary to explain what I'm trying to accomplish. I didn't think the solution would be specific to my code, which is why I didn't post it. I'll add the html now. I can post my CSS too but I'm not sure what you guys need to see, and I don't want to post my entire stylesheet obviously.

Comment: Your description of the problem is rather puzzling. Are you simply trying to put the two iframes side-by-side?

Comment: I haven't read through the posted answer yet, but just in case that doesn't work I'll try to explain. I'm trying to put the two iframes side-by-side so that I can scroll through them in a similar manner to how the images are scrolled through at the top of this page: http://agility-html.sevenspark.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put two iframes side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737427/how-to-put-two-iframes-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain this, try making a outer container that is about 1000px wide. Now you want to make each iframe 500px wide so they can both fit.  Then you want to float the top iframe left and the bottom iframe right.  If it doesn't work try adjusting the width of the iframe because if you have padding or margin on it that will make it more than 500px and break the float.

Help with floating. http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but will this make it so that both of the iframes are in view? I only want one iframe to be visible at a time. I already have the javascript for a button to scroll between the two. I just need to position them side-by-side with only one showing in the parent <section> at a time.

Comment: Then simply stick the `iframes` within a container that's wide enough to show just one of them. If the `iframes` are going to be side-by-side or on top of each other, you just need to play either with the `left` position or `z-index` to toggle between them.

Comment: Anytime. Glad I could help.